# Python parse excel files based on the excel template

Tags: python, excel, templates

The basic problem is this: users may load the excel template file, that looks something like this:

`temlate.xls` example:

```
    | Column A    | Column B   |
    | ----------  | ---------- |
    | {% for line in lines %}  |
    | {{ line.a}} | {{line.b}} |
    | {% endfor %}             |
    | ------------------------ |
    | Footer                   |
```

Then, when they upload some real data excel file,

```
    | Column A | Column B |
    | -------- | -------- |
    | Cell 1   | Cell 2   |
    | Cell 3   | Cell 4   |
    | ------------------- |
    | Footer              |
```

the process will take into account the template, returning something like:
`{'lines': [{'a': 'Cell 1', 'b': 'Cell 2'}, {'a': 'Cell 3', 'b': 'Cell 4'}]}`

The Django template syntax is just for reference, anything will do obviously.
At this point, i'm not even sure how to google such problem. Any suggestions with packages or articles will be appreciated. I believe even the reverse flow (export date to xls from template), will help.

Delving into openpyxl and related packages did not yield any result. There are code-based templates (basically a set of python classes), there is also a 'get original and put new data on top' flow, but couldn't find anything close to my problem.

Comment: You have a template and want to add data to it... so why doesn't Openpyxl, Xlwings or Win32com not fulfill this?

Comment: 1. I dont want to add data, but to read it. 2 I dont have a template, but rather users can upload/reupload templates, which the process has to use, while parsing data from the real excel files, which also users provide. In this way the template  represents some sort of anchoring map, for the process to know which cells should be parsed, up to which point, and how they should be mapped in the resulting list of dicts.